# How to use JSON.parse on old devices?

Tags: javascript, json

Inherited a very old project that supports the old devices (currently testing on Nokia N81). The main problem is that i need to parse json and it's not supported natively, so i used this https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js. It works fine on pc, but on nokia fails. I can't receive any errors, just nothing happens. If `json.parse` is removed all works fine including AJAX. Is there any solutions for old devices?

P.S.
Please do not offer jquery or other frameworks, i  need plain js solution.

Comment: The easiest is `eval()` after you've determined it's indeed valid; look into jQuery's source code for `$.parseJSON()`.

Comment: Btw, why can't you receive any errors? Does that mean there *are* no errors or even if there were you wouldn't see them?

Comment: @Jack there simply no source code or any console on nokia phones.

Comment: How are you _getting_ your JSON data? If you can put it into HTML directly, `<script>var foo = /*JSON code goes here*/</script>` could be a way of having the browser "parse" it automatically using its standard JS engine. You could also try to create a `script` element containing this code dynamically, or make it JSONP-"ish" by requesting a script resource that contains this kind of code.

Comment: @Kirix, I haven't tried it on a Nokia but it might be worth trying to programatically trap errors (via try/catch and window.onerror) and pushing them back to the server.

Comment: @Kirix http://www.jsconsole.com might be useful  as it allows you to create a remote debugging session - all the `console.log()` calls are sent back to your browser.

Comment: I would expect there was an error introduced in the user-code and not the library. Definitely find out *why* the JSON shim is failing .. also, there is now `json3.js` which supersedes `json2.js` (and there is an alternate version of `json2.js` with a different implementation), so might want to see if one of those just "magically work" when dropped in ..

Answer (score -1):

`jQuery.parseJSON` is implemented like this:

```
return ( new Function( "return " + json ) )();
```

See [jQuery.parseJSON code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e3a802cbf7d66d88e3659ad344bce86b99d029be/src/core.js#L523) in the 1.9 branch.

Comment: @michael Worth noting that the [MDN entry for `JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Browser_compatibility) uses `eval` in its code. There are valid uses for `eval`, this may be one of them.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I disagree that a primitive eval like this is ideal (even if done in jQuery, which is hardly stellar here) - the better solution would be to find out why it doesn't work on said platform, and then go from there. Do note that the standard `json2.js` *does* use an eval, but *also* takes great care to ensure that only valid JSON is allowed.

Comment: @Anthony I'll revise my earlier comment to say "don't use eval yourself" it's a direct route to security flaws. The existing solutions (MDN, json2) are tried and tested by thousands of people.